# Override IE email auto-formatting in rich-text editor

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, hyperlink, freetext

Our site makes use of [FreeTextBox](http://freetextbox.com/demos/), a web-based, rich-text editor. In IE, but in not Firefox, if a user types in something like:

> someone@blah

IE automatically creates a `mailto` hyperlink. I have tested this with other text editors out there and the story is the same with all of them.

Can I override this browser behavior somehow from within my application?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be done from within the browser or even as a registry setting adjustment for IE.  The same behavior exists for website urls and unc paths as well. Using markdown avoids this with the textarea element, but that is understandably not an ideal end-user wysiwyg editor.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the MSHTML editor, which (I'm guessing all) Windows browsers use to instantiate rich text editors.  There's a setting called [IDM_AUTOURLDETECT_MODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769893%28VS.85%29.aspx) that lets you decide if the autolinking will take place, and the default is true (other browsers apparently set it to false on instantiation, hence no autolinking in Firefox.)

Unfortunately, until recently Microsoft didn't have a mapping from the command ID to a command identifier string, so the function wasn't accessible via Javascript prior to IE9.

I just tried it out in IE9 and can confirm that, for that version and presumably all future ones, you can override the feature by calling

```
document.execCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false);
```

Note that it's IE9+ only, so you're still stuck for previous versions, and that you'll want to wait until the DOM is loaded before you call it and have some error handling around it, etc, etc.

There's a good summary of the original issue [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/17/prevent-automatic-hyperlinking-in-contenteditable-html.aspx), and a discussion of the fix in the minor change list [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/15/ie9-beta-minor-change-list.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0).